# How to find file name of page that makes XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a page that makes a `XMLHttpRequest` to a php file. In this php file I need the file name of the page that made the request.

```
                           XMLHttpRequest
variable-page-name.html -------------------> request-processor.php
                                        (needs 'variable-page-name.html')
```

**Edit: I have one requirement: I can't use php on the page that makes the request. The file name must either be obtained in the javascript on the request page, or in the processor.php**

So far I have been working with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in the php file. I realise it might also be possible for javascript to pass on a variable containing the file name. Let me repeat that I can't use php on the request page.

It is part of a very simple CMS that generates a change request through, and only through, javascript.

I am interested in what your thoughts are:

- How do I obtain the file name?
- Is it possible to get the file name from an 'unforgeable' source? (`HTTP_REFERER` is based on a header which can be modified by the user, if I am not mistaken.)
- Otherwise, is it best to rely on javascript or on php for this?
- Concerning security issues, do you perhaps have suggestions on how to validate this file name variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the file name from an 'unforgeable' source?

Sort of, you can't trust anything from the client side, but you can generate one-time keys and have them use those as the file names

> Is it best to rely on javascript or on php for this?

You'll need to use both, *JavaScript* by default won't send anything more than the referer, but that doesn't mean you can't add custom headers or queries to the request

> Concerning security issues, do you perhaps have suggestions on how to validate this file name variable? How can I limit the damage that could be done? Limit perhaps the directory accessible.

- Require that the client is logged in; make the page die before anything happens otherwise
- Send one-time keys so that once a key is used, the page must be refreshed (or an ajax call is required) to get a new key
- Rate limit how frequently the page can be called pet client, do this entirely server side by looking at the time
- Set the upload directory as `403 Forbidden`, do all requests to it via another script which reads the file contents (i.e. to make sure the server does not execute uploaded files)

---

Here is something I was playing around with as stackoverflow was in read only mode, you may want to use an entirely different method though

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method, url); // e.g. "POST", "/upload.php"
xhr.setRequestHeader('one-time-key', keyForThisRequest);
xhr.send(data); // e.g. a FormData instance
```

Then e.g. (depends on php version etc)

```php
if (isset($_SESSION["is_admin"])) {
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    if (isset($_SESSION["one-time-key"]) && $headers["one-time-key"] == $_SESSION["one-time-key"]) {
        // etc
    } else {
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: The one time keys you mention are the same thing as the nonces I mention. The wordpress docs have some decent information about using nonces (for wordpress). http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces

Comment: Thank you. I can only let javascript generate a one time key. Will it still work? So how do I obtain the file name of the page that makes the request?